# If Conditional Containing an AND of pointer and integer

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm looking at some C code that contains this statement.

```
if (
     ((uint8_t *)row)[byte] & (1 << (8-bit))
   ) 
value |= (value + 1);
```

What would be the meaning and purpose of putting the AND of a pointer and an integer inside the conditional parentheses?

Comment: Where is the *AND of a pointer*?

Comment: "What would be the meaning and purpose of putting the AND of a pointer and an integer inside the conditional parentheses?" - nothing. It's `and`ing two integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't what it's doing.

```
(uint8_t *)row
```

cast row to pointer-to-unsigned-byte

```
((uint8_t *)row)[byte]
```

... and apply array addressing to retrieve the unsigned byte `byte` bytes forward from there. (Array addressing and pointer math are somewhat interchangable; `pointerval[intval]` means the same thing as `*(pointerval + intval)`.

So that means

```
((uint8_t *)row)[byte] & (1 << (8-bit))
```

retrieves the `byte`th unsigned byte from the row, and masks out everything but the `bit`th bit.

Finally, putting it all together,

```
if ( ((uint8_t *)row)[byte] & (1 << (8-bit)) )
```

tests whether the result of the expression is true (nonzero).

So this is asking whether a particular bit of a particular byte in the row is nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

There are meanings, in other contexts, but that's not what's happening here.

It's casting `row` (which I assume is a pointer of some sort) to a `uint8_t *`, and then picking out the `byte`-th `uint8_t` in that array.  *That* is then bitwise-anded with the shifted-left stuff.

It's logically the same as:

```
uint8_t shifted = (1 << (8 - bit))
uint8_t *rowptr = (uint8_t *)row;
uint8_t rowval = rowptr[byte];
uint8_t combined = (rowval & shifted);

if (combined)  // or, if (combined != 0)
  value |= (value + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case is for cheking if a specific bit is on.

Answer (score 1):

It's testing whether bit 7 of `row[byte]` is set or not. The `&` binary operator is the bitwise `AND` operator, not the logical AND operator. `1<<(8-bit)` is an expression commonly used to generate a bit mask to isolate one bit.

`row` may be a generic pointer, so `(uint8_t *)row` is used to cast this pointer to be a poiniter to an array of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an AND of the pointer. You have a pointer, and then you are [byte] above that starting location *that* is what is being ANDed.